Flutter official GitHub repository gets added to my source control on VSCode
I have this problem that Flutter official GitHub repository gets added to my source control on vscode.
This is a picture
What should I do here? Is it safe to just ignore it? Should I pull and push the changes?
This is my first project and I don't have much programming and working with GitHub experience, so I haven't done anything. Please tell me what to do.

You're right, you wouldn't want that to happen because you're not working on (making changes to) the Flutter framework itself. May I ask in which location on your PC you installed Flutter? It should be in a completely different folder than your Flutter project/app that you are working on.

Flutter SDK is in C:\src\flutter. My project is on desktop. I disconnected Flutter repository but my source control still contains changes from Flutter official repo.

in vs code - use Ctrl + Shift + P  . then create a flutter application in your local directory, then open that flutter project. I hope It will solve.
